# What does the sentence "Songs often speak of or sing of the importance of music to the heart and to the soul"?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> Songs often speak of or sing of the importance of music to the heart and to the soul.

How should I analyze the above sentence? Is "songs" the subject, "speak of/sing of" the verb?

But how can "songs" speak something?

Can anyone please explain the meaning of this sentence?

The above sentence is from a youtube video. Below is the link. The line is at about 2:56

[bbc learning english](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8YEqkW43tcM)

Comment: Did you look up the definition of [speak](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/speak)?  Among its meanings are "to express thoughts, opinions, or feelings orally" and "to express feelings by other than verbal means".

Answer (score 2):

It's a style; figuratively, maybe! Don't think that subjects here are the ones performing the action. That's how it's written! You need to keep those things in mind, just learn as they are.

> City *witnessed* a big chaos yesterday 
>  This battleground has *seen* the blood of hundreds of people

In all such cases, non-living (inanimate objects) haven't performed the actions.